# Plotting regions in complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Plot the region represented by $\frac{π}{3}\leqslant \arg\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\leqslant\frac{2π}{3}$ in the Argand plane.

I know that such inequalities usually represent the minor or major arcs of the circle and the area bounded by them,but I can't figure out this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unclear.  What is the meaning of z+1\z-1 ?

Comment: It is just divison. My apologies, the notation I used may have created some confusion. The question has been edited, you will see the meaning now

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Think of all arcs like $$\arg\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)=\theta$$but keeping $\theta$ in the given range.[image]

Please ask if you need more details.

Edit:
Adding [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/balqw6rybh)
[image]

Comment: I can't understand how you derived that graph( more specifically the shaded part), can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: Can you try drawing the graph for $\arg(\frac{z+1}{z-1})=\frac{\pi}{3}$ ?

Comment: Yes, I know how to draw the graph, but I don't understand how you put it in the range.

Comment: Think what would happen if you draw the graph for pi/3, then for pi/3+0.01, then for pi/3+0.02 and so on, all the way to 2*pi/3. Check [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n0kuke6pai) out. The ugly looking formula on the LHS in the graph is simply  the LHS you gave. I am changing the parameter from pi/3 to 2pi/3 in the graph. Think what would happen if you change the parameter smoothly